# Stop scrolling when link is opened

Tags: html, css

Whenever my link is opened the webpage is apparently bigger than my setting (810 px in width) so when it's opened it starts scrolling in both ways. How can i stop this?
(This is for a HTML tab on Facebook with clickable 'pictures'.

and

So whenever the link is clicked and replaced the site it's bigger and it overfloats. How can i fix this?
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Testside2/649904311740074?id=649904311740074&sk=app_208195102528120

Comment: Have you tried adding `body { overflow: hidden;  }` to your CSS file?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't really work. Can i in some way resize the link so it fits?

Comment: @Vijaya: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Is this the answer you're looking for? http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/facebook-iframe-apps-getting-rid-of-scrollbars/

Comment: You're going to have to explain better what you want to do. Saying "fix this" is meaningless without that.